# Find the limit of this series using the ratio test.

Tags: real-analysis, ratio, absolute-convergence

$a_n=\frac{c^n(n^2+3n+5)}{5^n(4n^n+3n+5)}$ where $c$  is a real constant
Find the limit as $n \to \infty$ of this series.

I’ve used the ratio test and written it in the form $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} $
Which gives me $\frac{c(n^2+5n+7)(4n^2+3n+5)}{5(16n^2+35n+9) (n^2+3n+5)}$
I don’t know what to do after this. Should I multiply the brackets or is there an easier way to find the limit?

Comment: When you say "of this series", do you mean $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$, or did you mean to use the word "sequence" instead of "series" (meaning you want $\lim_{j\to\infty}a_j$)?

Comment: Also, is that supposed to be an $n^n$ in the denominator, or should it be $n^2$ (based on your attempt to apply the ratio test)?